# Merging several joins into a single select / case

Tags: t-sql, pivot, case

I am currently querying a table 4 times using different criteria and then using left joins as part of a much larger query to return all the data.  The larger query does not run particularly quickly and I am fairly certain that my current approach is not efficient.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to somehow use a CASE statement to increment one of the 4 columns.  My 4 queries currently are:

```
SELECT ts.department, 
                         Sum([hours]) AS ChargeableTimeYTD 
                  FROM   bwbfiles.sos.timesummary ts 
                  WHERE  category = 'C' 
                         AND [year] = '2019' 
                  GROUP  BY department


SELECT ts.department, 
                         Sum([hours]) AS ChargeableTimeMTD 
                  FROM   bwbfiles.sos.timesummary ts 
                  WHERE  category = 'C' 
                         AND [year] = '2019' 
                         AND [period] = 4 
                  GROUP  BY department


SELECT ts.department, 
                         Sum([hours]) AS NonChargeableTimeProBono 
                  FROM   bwbfiles.sos.timesummary ts 
                  WHERE  category = 'NC' 
                         AND ( [act_code] = '001N' 
                                OR [act_code] = '00N6' ) 
                         AND [year] = '2019' 
                  GROUP  BY department


SELECT ts.department, 
                         Sum([hours]) AS NonChargeableTimeNonProBono 
                  FROM   bwbfiles.sos.timesummary ts 
                  WHERE  category = 'NC' 
                         AND ( [act_code] <> '001N' 
                               AND [act_code] <> '00N6' ) 
                         AND [year] = '2019' 
                  GROUP  BY department
```

The aim would be to end up with a query result with 5 columns
Department, ChargeableTimeYTD, ChargeableTimeMTD, NonChargeableTimeProBono, NonChargeableTimeNonProBono

Or instead of CASE would I remove the group by department from each bit and have a query that produced 3 columns

Department, Hours, Category (where Category is ChargeableTimeYTD/ChargeableTimeMTD etc...etc...) and then pivot that into 5 columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `[year]` really a string datatype rather than an integer of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do what i think you're asking for

```
SELECT ts.department, 
    Sum(case when category = 'C' then [hours] else 0 end) AS ChargeableTimeYTD,
    Sum(case when category = 'C' and [period] = 4 then [hours] else 0 end) AS ChargeableTimeMTD,
    Sum(case when category = 'NC' and ([act_code] = '001N' or [act_code] = '00N6') then [hours] else 0 end) AS NonChargeableTimeProBono,
    Sum(case when category = 'NC' and ([act_code] <> '001N' or [act_code] <> '00N6') then [hours] else 0 end) AS NonChargeableTimeNonProBono
FROM   bwbfiles.sos.timesummary ts 
where [year] = '2019'
and [category] in ('C','NC')
GROUP  BY department
```

Comment: Performance may be improved, and the logic simplified, by using `... where [year] = '2019' ...`. It could also filter on `category in ( 'C', 'NC' )` to reduce the number of rows processed.

Comment: `[act_code] <> '001N' or [act_code] <> '00N6'` was `and`, not `or`, in the original query.

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much - make so much sense when you see it so not sure why my mind was thinking of pivot.  There are a lot of areas where I can use this technique so thank you very much again.  Ed.